# SQL Server 2017 Always-ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, windows-server

I have configured Distributed AG from DC1 to DC2 (SQL 2017 Ent edition with CU22 version)

DC1- DB1, DB2 and DC2-DB3, DB4

1. I have restarted DC1-DB1 SQL services, after restart DC1-DB2 should be primary. But still DC1-DB2 showing as  secondary.  Is this is the expected behaviour?
2. I have restarted DC1-DB2 SQL services, nothing happen - still DC1-DB1 is primary. Is this is the expected behaviour?

DC1 AG configurations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exact [similar question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/102465/sql-server-always-on.html) was asked on new Microsoft Q and A Site. I created a 2 node WSFC with AG configured for SQL Server databases. To simply put WSFC did not initiated a failover because the parameter `Failure-Condition Level` is `default 3`. And as per Microsoft official document [Configure a flexible automatic failover policy for an Always On availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/configure-failureconditionlevel-property-settings?view=sql-server-ver15) for a SQL Server restart to trigger a failover you need `Failure-Condition Level`=1

This can be changed via Powershell, TSQL or from cluster GUI. One below shows value in cluster GUI

[image]